# Web (jsp servlet) application hosting

Tags: web-server, hosting

I have a jsp servlet application which allows users to listen meida files(audio video). I have 2 solutions. 1 st solution-. upload media files to youtube and keep the url in my database. when a user needs an audio file, link to the youtube and play. 2nd solution is that host in a commercial hosting server. My application is not for profit (no ads, no any hidden business purpose). It is for all people's benefit.
On the other hand, I have problems with these solutions. If I upload them to youtube, someone can use media files for commercials or vulnerable activities or edit them and do none ethical things to them. If I go to a hosting server (purchase a commercial vps and host..) the disk space is a problem and money is also problem for me to continue. I expect a best solution from you all experts and your reviews will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you load your content onto the web, (then with the limited exception of DRM technologies) then anyone can simply download your files locally.

This fact is true of any content that is hosted with a paid-for-by-you service, or with a free-to-use-but-ad-revenue service like youtube. So the key thing is, that if you absolutely want to protect your files 100%, then don't put them on the pubic internet.

However... generally, to get started you might as well co-host your media content with your same service provider as your jsp servlet application host,  as most commercial shared java servlet hosting companies provide 20GB disk space for only a few USD per month.

If you have particular technical requirements, then you could add them as comments, or update your question with further details.

(its worth mentioning that for any non-revenue generating content that you want to put on the web, that if you host it yourself then the more traffic you get the more the cost to you, however for services like you-tube, the more traffic your video gets, the more ads that youtube can display, hence they may even pay you some money.)

Comment: Thank you very much & grateful for your advise.I asked some hosting companies with my requirement and they said that I have to go to a VPS according to my requirement which could cost me a lot.So now my intention is to put files in youtube and allow users to play media files through a player linked to YouTube. Do you feel any disadvantages than publishing their ads?

Comment: The answer that question is highly dependent on your requirements. If you are trying to create a "brand" or some other context in which you want to control the presentation, then youtube could be a poor choice. However if you are targeting the kind of young consumer crowd that is youtube viewers then that is a good place to be.

Comment: Re ad disadvantages: I see their ads as an advantage! Basically hosting content costs money, and someone has to pay for it. So either you have to setup some business to sell ads, or pay yourself. I prefer to let youtube or some service handle that part. (its also worth noting that youtube is not the only ad-revenue content network, there is http://vimeo.com/ and very many other services that might be more appropriate for your need see - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_hosting_services

Comment: actually here are some comparisons of video hosting networks that have some pros and cons sections the wikipedia article seems to be a little bit "wall of words" - http://www.dvguru.com/2006/04/07/ten-video-sharing-services-compared/  http://groundwire.org/resources/articles/online-video-hosting

Comment: I don't know how far I should thank you.:) I got many problems solved by your links. And special thank should be offered to them as well. As I mentioned in my question, I have no any business idea from my site.My site some thing like,knowledge sharing of meditations and some relevant media contents which can help for people.Therefore I don't expect any revenue or famous for my self.It is just for benefit of people in the world.I am to embed Youtube in my site and upload content to youtube. My concern of that, some one can edit them and do crucial bad things and upload everywhere. But

Comment: .. but even if I maintain my server uploading the content, I won't able to avoid or stop such bad things(I think so) as you mentioned in your answer. It doesnot matter that people download and listen or watch any times, but not change the content and abuse them. Once again I thank you more and more for your advice.